# Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open set. Is $f^{-1}(E)$ necessarily an open set?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open set. Is $f^{-1}(E)$ necessarily an open set?

Basically, we have just started to study functions with the form $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and even though I am aware of the definitions and believe I have at least a basic understanding of them, I have no idea how to answer of even approach those kind of questions.

I have no intuition whatsoever to what the answer would be. However, I am pretty sure that if $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(E)$ does not have to be an open set (because for example we can say that $f(x)=c$ for all $x\in E$.

Can someone provide some guidance?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the definition of continuity that you are using? The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition?

Comment: The reason for this question is that as you advance to the study of more general topological spaces, you'll discover that a function is *defined* to be continuous if the pre-image of an open set is always open.  You are correct that the (forward) image of an open set under a continuous function need not be open.

Comment: @RobertShore There are several definitions of continuous, depending on context. In calculus and analysis, the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition is conventional. There functions are _defined_ to be continuous iff for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that [...]. The fact that most of topology defines continuity in terms of inverse images doesn't make the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ formulation less of a a definition. Of course, the fact that the two definitions agree where they both make sense is a useful theorem, and half of that theorem is what the OP is asked to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $x_0 \in f^{-1}(E).$  Then $y=f(x_0) \in E$.  $E$ is open, so $\exists \epsilon_1 \gt 0$ such that $\lvert z-y \rvert \lt \epsilon_1 \Rightarrow z \in E.$  Because $f$ is continuous, $\exists \delta \gt 0$ such that $\lvert x-x_0 \rvert \lt \delta \Rightarrow \lvert f(x) -f(x_0) \rvert = \lvert f(x) - y \rvert \lt \epsilon_1 \Rightarrow f(x) \in E \Rightarrow x \in f^{-1}(E).$

Set $\epsilon = \delta$.  Then $\lvert x-x_0 \rvert \lt \epsilon \Rightarrow x \in f^{-1}(E).$  But $x_0$ was an arbitrary point in $f^{-1}(E)$ so we have proved that for any arbitrary point $x_0 \in f^{-1}(E) ~\exists \epsilon \gt 0$ such that $\lvert x-x_0 \rvert \lt \epsilon \Rightarrow x \in f^{-1}(E)$, and that fact in turn guarantees that $f^{-1}(E)$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is **yes**. In fact, this is the definition of continuity in the general setting of topological spaces (i.e. $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if, for each open $U\subseteq Y$, we have that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$).

---

To prove the desired result, consider the following approach.

Fix an open subset $E\subseteq\mathbb R$ and a point $x\in f^{-1}(E)$. Then $f(x)\in E$, and because $E$ is open there exists a small ball $B$ around $f(x)$ such that $B\subseteq E$. Try using your definition of continuity to show that there is a subset $A\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$ such that $A$ is an open ball around $x$ satisfying $A\subseteq f^{-1}(E)$.

Comment: We were taught the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. I am unable to complete the proof.